# Elastix Call Center Module "How to disable Agent Auto Answer?"

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I have Elastix Version 2.4 and Call Center Module

The default behavior for the an Agent logged into a queue is:
Call from inbound route ---->if an agent is available--->the agent hears a beep and the call is started.

"How to disable Agent Auto Answer?":
Can I change this behavior to :
Call from inbound route ---->if an agent is available---> ring the agent phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for that you need use static or callback agents (not call agent to queue).

For more info see

http://asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/ACD_id289508.html

In `agents.conf` file and add this paramters:

`ackcall=yes ; this will make the agent accept or refuse the call before the channel is opened`
 
`acceptdtmf=#; the key agent press to accept the call`

Comment: I added agents as static agents in the queue configuration, and i am using elastic callcenter agent console to login agents.please can you give me more explanation.

Comment: IF you added agents as static, it will call when you put call in queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot artheops , I figured it out from the link you added :)